# Physical argument that the Ising model has no phase transition for nonzero external field

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spin-models

I have seen rigorous proofs on why the Ising model does not have a phase transition for $h\ne 0$ (via the Lee-Yang theorem or GHS inequality). However, these proofs don't shed much physical intuition onto the subject, so I am curious on how a more heuristic/physical argument can be given. I would hope that the argument could be generalized to classical spin models with discrete symmetry and possibly continuous symmetry (e.g., XY model).

Comment: I am confused by the $h \neq 0$ condition. Is Ising model supposed to have a phase transition for $h = 0$ (in $1\mathrm{D}$)?

Comment: I'm consider a $d$-dim Ising model, where $d$ is not necessarily 1

Comment: The lack of a phase transition for such systems follows fairly intuitively (though not rigorously) from Landau-Ginzburg theory. One expects the effective functional for the free energy as a function of magnetization for an Ising (or XY, Heisenberg, ...) model in an external field to always have a unique minimum which varies continuously for all $\beta > 0$.

Comment: More details can be found in Landau, Lifshitz, Statistical Physics. Part 1. Paragraph 144: "Effect of an external field on a phase transition"

Comment: Two comments: 1) I doubt that there is a very convincing heuristic argument, at least not without further assumptions on the model. Indeed, there is a phase transition at nonzero $h$ for the Potts model (with,say, a magnetic field coupling only to one of the colors). 2) I just want to point out that a version of the Lee-Yang theorem does apply to the XY model.